# Courier-imap results in chmod error when started

Tags: imap, courier

I'm using CentOS5 and cannot start IMAP.

```
-bash-3.1# service courier-imap start
Starting Courier-Imap: chmod: cannot access `run': No such file or directory
```

I'm not entirely sure what that error is referring to?  I am able to stop and start other services such as lighttpd

Answer (score 1):

Does /var/run/courier-imap exist?

Please make the directory and try starting the service again.

```
mkdir -p /var/run/courier-imap
```

Comment: that returns "No such file or directory"

Comment: still throwing the same error

-bash-3.1# mkdir -p /var/run/courier-imap
-bash-3.1# service courier-imap start
Starting Courier-Imap: chmod: cannot access `run': No such file or directory

Comment: try stracing it to get the full path to what it's trying to open?